# call method A in a class B in a header file?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, methods, subclass

```
class person{
...
public:
get_age(){..}
...
};

class society{
private:
person Ann;
....
};
```

I am not sure how to call the method get_age in a header file with the most minimum declaing in class person? I tried to seach but could not find the exact example.
Something like that
header file:

```
society tennis;
tennis.Ann.get_age()
```

I failed with this, trying to access method get_age() from the class person, as the method belongs to person but not to society. How to access get_age() with minimum statements.

Comment: There is nothing special about header files (or non-header files). Please explain what you've tried and failed with.

Comment: You can't access the `Ann` member of `tennis` because `Ann` is in a **`private`** section.  Stuff in `private` section is not accessible to functions or classes outside of the defined class.  In other words, `private` members of `class society` are not accessible outside of `society` methods.  Try making the member public or change your design or implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating class instances (objects) in headers is a bad practice in common. As soon as you include your header into any .cpp file, its content is pasted into your .cpp file, leading to multiple definition of the created object. E.g. the compiler/linker will say that your object `tennis` is defined twice - in your header and in e.g. main.cpp that includes your header.